# How do I check if a Visual C++ argument is a valid drive letter?

Tags: c++, windows, drive

Like the title says, I have a C++ program and the user passes in an argument. I want to validate whether the argument passed is a valid DOS/Windows drive letter (i.e. C:. D:. E:) and that the drive exists on the system. How do I do this?

Comment: Even if the drive letter was valid you may not be able to access it for other reasons so you always wrap the call in a `try catch` block so if you get an exception I would presume the drive letter was duff or you didn't have permission to access it or some other error

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284110/get-a-list-of-the-available-drives-and-their-sizes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the type of a drive with [GetDriveType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939.aspx) - which also tells you if a drive doesn't exist or isn't availble

Or the 'correct' way is to [enumerate through all the drives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)